# How to parse children recursively using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having my jQuery code as following (which is working fine):

```
$('[RptrRowEnableAutoHeight=""True""]').each(function () {
        var ch = 10;
        $(this).children().each(function(){ch += $(this).height();}); 
        $(this).height(ch);
});
```

The above works only for the immediate children of the root element.  How can I achieve the same for all nested child elements.

This is a special case for us as the layout was developed using absolute positioning (almost everywhere).  At this moment, we are unable to modify entire layout with flow-layout.

In simple, I would like to have all (container) controls to expand (their height/width) automatically to enclose their child elements in a proper fashion (without any scrollbars/hiding).

thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `$(this).find('*').each(...`